# Hibernate how to join if unknown which join exists

Tags: hibernate, join

Hi i want to select my entities in hql like this

```
select ent from Entity as ent
where 
    (
        ent.author.userID = :userID 
        OR 
        ent.userID = :userID
    )
```

but if ent.author is not set, but ent.userID is set, i'll get no result either, because ent.author can't be joined.

Any ideas how to query something like that?

Comment: Don't you need to use a Left join to ensure Entity is loaded even if Author is null.

Comment: is it possible to left join without manually writing them? because in reality the joins are much bigger like "ent.ent2.ent3.author.userID"